# I thought of "we are greater within" as a nice phrase that might be cool in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

Thus far, I have researched Latin lightly and have passively watched multiple Latin videos. I would say I could probably figure out how to write a sentence in Latin given enough time with Numen and Wiktionary. Though I just want to be sure that the translation I came to would be grammatically correct and, even better, effectual in it's message. I think I got a somewhat workable translation:

**(Nōs?) intrā nōs (nōs?) ultrā sumus.**

*We are greater within **ourselves**.*

I am not quite sure where the nominative nōs would go. I can't quite tell if it would be at beginning of the sentence characteristic of the most common SOV structure or if it would go after the accusative nōs.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The best place for the nominative *nos* is nowhere. You should leave it out, unless you want to particularly stress it (it is **us** who are greater, not those other guys). In that case the default position would be at the start of the sentence.

(This is also why one of the most well-known words in the Latin language, *ego*, is not all that frequently encountered in actual Latin: "I think, therefore I am" is [*Cogito, ergo sum*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum), and definitely not *Ego cogito, ergo ego sum*.)

*Ultra* does not mean "greater", that would be *maior* (or *major*, depending on personal taste!). Also, while *intra nos* is technically correct, it sounds a little like "inside ourselves". I believe "within" is more succinctly expressed by *intus*.

When you know somebody "within and without", in Latin you could say: *Ego te intus et in cute novi.* (Persius, [Saturae 3,30](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/persius.html#III)) -- literally: "I know you within and under the skin." (Nice work undermining my previous point about *ego* there, Aule Persi!) No need to replicate this silly pleonasm though ...

Thus we get:

> Intus majores sumus.

Comment: And if you're talking about the TARDIS (or some versions of Baba Yaga's hut), you can even omit the _est_ and just say _maius intus_.

Comment: @tony Non *novi* sed [*nōvi*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnosco) ;-)

Comment: I wasn't even close! My goodness.